# Не работает проект в Unity с использованием NetTopologySuite

Tags: c#, unity3d

Если просто запускать сцену, то все работает отлично, но как только я добавляю в скрипт одного gameObject'а строку `var builder = new ConformingDelaunayTriangulationBuilder();` (в методе `Start()`) из библиотеки `NetTopologySuite.Triangulate`, то сцена больше не запускается.
В инспекторе у gameObject'а пишет, что скрипт не может быть запущен и его нужно проверить на ошибки, но ошибок нет.

Может я как-то не так импортировал `NetTopologySuite`? Скачал [здесь](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite/), потом из скаченного файла достал dll и поместил в проект Unity.

Вот сам скрипт:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = System.Random;
using NetTopologySuite.Triangulate;

public class Board : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Pattern pattern;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    private static Random random;

    void Start()
    {
        random = new Random();
        //var builder = new ConformingDelaunayTriangulationBuilder();
        Debug.Log("Triangles");
    }
}
```

Сейчас все работает нормально, но если раскомментировать строку, то работать перестанет.

Это скрин после запуска с раскомментированной строкой:

[image]

И в пакетах все есть:

[image]

Comment: В `try-catch` оберните вызов. Быть может исключение возникает, но вы его почему-то не видите. Через NuGet эту библиотеку пробовали ставить без копирования руками?

Comment: @aepot обернул в `try-catch`, но ничего не изменилось, ошибки нет, скрипт также не видит. Через NuGet пробовал ставить, но не работает, потому что Unity не видит ее, а чтобы библиотеку стало видно, ее нужно скачивать и закидывать в проект (ну как я понял)

Comment: NuGet должен добавлять ссылку и втыкать в сборку библиотеку автоматически, оно так работает. Либо библиотека несовместима с вашим проектом, либо неправильный нугет.